# Ansible - Using a lineinfile loop will result in an inverted/reverse host order in file. Any workarounds?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a file that looks like this:

```
#### START CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 5000 ####
server1:5000 online
server2:5000 online
server3:5000 online
#### END CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 5000 ####

[...]<<< SOME OTHER TEXT HERE >>>[...]

#### START CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 8000 ####
server1:8000 online
server2:8000 online
server3:8000 online
#### END CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 8000 ####


[...]<<< MORE TEXT HERE >>>[...]


#### START CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 12000 ####
server1:12000 online
server2:12000 online
server3:12000 online
#### END CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 12000 ####
```

I have a pretty large play that deploys new servers, adds them (in alphabetical order) to an in-memory inventory and then performs some other tasks.
One of the last tasks is the following, which adds the new servers (server4, server5, server6) to the aforementioned file:

```
- name: Add the newly created servers to the status file in each section
  lineinfile:
    path: /opt/service/servers.lst
    line: "{{ item.line }}"
    insertbefore: "{{ item.insertbefore }}"
  loop:
    - line: '{{ inventory_hostname }}:5000 {{ detected_server_status }}'
      insertbefore: '#### END CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 5000 ####'
    - line: '{{ inventory_hostname }}:8000 {{ detected_server_status }}'
      insertbefore: '#### END CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 8000 ####'
    - line: '{{ inventory_hostname }}:12000 {{ detected_server_status }}'
      insertbefore: '#### END CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 12000 ####'
```

The task does work fine, but what is bugging me is the fact that the servers are added in reverse order when using the loop (which is not the case if I just add three separate "lineinfile" tasks for each of the "blocks"):

```
#### START CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 5000 ####
server1:5000 online
server2:5000 online
server3:5000 online
server6:5000 online
server5:5000 online
server4:5000 online
#### END CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 5000 ####

[...]<<< SOME OTHER TEXT HERE >>>[...]

#### START CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 8000 ####
server1:8000 online
server2:8000 online
server3:8000 online
server6:8000 online
server5:8000 online
server4:8000 online
#### END CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 8000 ####


[...]<<< MORE TEXT HERE >>>[...]


#### START CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 12000 ####
server1:12000 online
server2:12000 online
server3:12000 online
server6:12000 online
server5:12000 online
server4:12000 online
#### END CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 12000 ####
```

As mentioned above, the inventory is in alphabetical order (I have debugged it and it's also visible in the other tasks that run in the correct order), so whatever it is... it's something related to the lineinfile loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since discovered that the order is actually not always reversed, it's simply completely unpredictable.

I did find a solution (well, more like a workaround than a perfect solution), so writing it here, maybe it will help someone else.
What ultimately fixed my issue was adding "throttle: 1" to the "lineinfile" task:

```
- name: Add the newly created servers to the status file in each section
  lineinfile:
    path: /opt/service/servers.lst
    line: "{{ item.line }}"
    insertbefore: "{{ item.insertbefore }}"
  loop:
    - line: '{{ inventory_hostname }}:5000 {{ detected_server_status }}'
      insertbefore: '#### END CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 5000 ####'
    - line: '{{ inventory_hostname }}:8000 {{ detected_server_status }}'
      insertbefore: '#### END CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 8000 ####'
    - line: '{{ inventory_hostname }}:12000 {{ detected_server_status }}'
      insertbefore: '#### END CUSTOM ANSIBLE BLOCK 12000 ####'
  throttle: 1
```

This causes the loop to run for each host, one at a time, so they will always appear in the correct order in the file.
My assumption is that there is some kind of bug / race condition when the loop runs on all hosts simultaneously, which results in an unpredictable behavior.

I will not mark this as the correct answer, maybe someone else will come up with a better solution in the future.